# Where I made mistake(s)? of $~-\frac{d\left(\Phi\right)}{dt}-L\frac{dI}{dt}=RI~$ of a coil with a long bar magnet?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

The very long bar magnet  and the coil exist .

I want to find out the amount of charges which flows as the bar magnet   is inserted deep enough into the coil.

$$  J:=\text{strength of magnetization of the bar magnet}  $$

$$  S:= \text{cross-sectional area of the bar magnet}  $$

$$  N:= \text{number of the turns of the coil}  $$

$$  R:=\text{total resistance of the coil}  $$

$$  L:=\text{self-inductance of the coil}  $$

$$  \Phi:=\text{sum of each magntic flux which penerates each surface of the turns of the coil}  $$

$$  I:=\text{current which flows the coil(as induced EMF occurs)}  $$

$~ \Phi_{}  ~$ is constant for any time .

What I can't get currently is the below equation .

$$  \color{red}{} -\frac{  d \left( \Phi \right)   }{ dt   } - L \frac{  dI  }{  dt  } =RI \color{black} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \left( 1 \right)  $$

I know Faraday's law of induction which can be represented in the below equation .

$$  \text{induced EMF of the coil}= -\frac{ d \left(  \Phi  \right)    }{  dt  }   $$

And also I know that the above EMF of the coil can  be represented by the below equation .

$$  \text{induced EMF of the coil} = -L \frac{  d \left( \text{current which flows the coil}  \right)   }{  dt  }   $$

So the $~ RI ~$  of the equation1 is a induced EMF of the coils .

And the each term of the LHS of the equation1 is also a induced EMF of the coil so the equation is false I think since $~ \left( 2 \left( \text{EMF}  \right) \neq \text{EMF}  \right)  ~$ is held .

Where I made mistake(s)?

Comment: We are assuming that the two ends of the coil are connected together?  Also, if (Φ) is constant, the d(Φ)/dt is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not make a mistake and your equation (1) should be correct, only the interpretation of the result is a bit different from what you suggested. Since $I$ is the total current through the coil, $RI$ is the total EMF. On the other hand,
$$
- \frac{d \Phi}{dt} \qquad \text{and} \qquad - L \frac{dI}{dt}
$$
both only account for *one component* of the EMF, namely the first for the one induced by the motion of the magnet and the second for the one caused by the self-inductance of the coil. The total EMF is the sum of the components, which is exactly what your equation (1) states.

Answer (score 2):

As the magnet enters the coil, producing flux through more and more turns, the emf produces current in the coil (if the ends are connected).  The self-inductance of the coil opposes this change in current.  Take the induced emf as positive and the second term as negative.